# Derive Text, Images, and LaTeX Equations from Websites

Tags: latex, wolfram-mathematica, html

Would it be possible to derive the text, images, and LaTeX equations from a particular website so that you can directly customize your own PDF without having the objects blurry? Only the  image will have a fixed resolution.

I realize that there are a couple ways of generating a PDF indirectly. Attempting to render a PDF from Wolfram MathWorld on the [Riemann Zeta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), for instance, would be possible by printing and saving it as a PDF via Chrome, but as you zoom in more closely, the LaTeX equations and text naturally become blurry. I tried downloading "Wolfram's CDF Player," but it contains only the syntax for Mathematica's libraries - not the helpful explanations that the Wolfram MathWorld provides. What would be required for me to extract the text, images, and LaTeX equations in a PDF file wihtout having them blurry?

Comment: You may better try your question here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have access to the LaTeX source that was used to produce the images in a way that isn't apparent from your question, the answer is "you cannot."  Casual inspection of the website linked implies that the LaTeX that is used to produce the equations is not readily available (it's probably on a backend system somewhere that produces the images that get put on the web server).

To a browser, it's just an image.  The method by which the image was produced is irrelevant to how it appears on the web page, and how it would appear in a PDF (ie. more pixelated than desired).

Note that if a website uses a vector-graphics format like SVG instead of a pixel based format like PNG or JPEG, then those will translate to PDF cleanly, and will zoom nicely.  That's a choice that would be made by the webmaster of the site in question.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the source reveals that the gifs depicting each equation have alt-text that approximates the LaTeX that would render them (it might be Mathematica code--I'm not familiar with Wolfram's tools).  Extracting a reasonable source wouldn't be impossible, but it would be hard.  The site is laid out with tables, so even with something like [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) parsing the HTML could be tricky.  Some equations are broken up into different gifs, so parsing them would be even trickier.  You'd also have to convert from whatever the alt-text is to LaTeX.

All in all, if you don't need to do a zillion pages, I'd suggest copy-pasting the text, saving the images, grabbing the alt-text of each image and doing the converting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For the given example, you could download the Mathematica notebook for that page. Maybe it is possible to parse something from that.